# How can you change int values in a matrix to float?

Tags: python, numpy

I have this code below:

```
import numpy as np

n = float(input("Starting number : " ))
m = float(input("Ending Number : "))

a = np.random.randint(n,m, size=(10,10))
print("\na : ", a)

top_left =  [a[0][:5], a[1][:5]]
top_right = [a[0][5:], a[1][5:]]
bot_left =  [a[2][:5], a[3][:5]]
bot_right = [a[2][5:], a[3][5:]]

print("\n")
print("1st quadrant : ", top_right)
print("2nd quadrant : ", top_left)
print("3rd quadrant : ", bot_left)
print("4th quadrant : ", bot_right)

print("\n")
avg1 = np.average(top_right)
print("Average of 1st quadrant : " ,avg1)

avg2 = np.average(top_left)
print("Average of 2nd quadrant : " ,avg2)

avg3 = np.average(bot_left)
print("Average of 3rd quadrant : " ,avg3)

avg4 = np.average(bot_right)
print("Average of 4th quadrant : " ,avg4)
```

The purpose is to create a 10x10 matrix and define the numbers within it between two user input numbers. Then I take the quadrants and find the average of each and give the output.

I've tried to research how to be able to input two float numbers, show a grid with float numbers, and find the average as a float number, but I couldn't figure it out.

Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm guessing I have to change a = np.random.randint(n,m, size=(10,10)), but I don't know to what or even if it's the right choice.

Comment: Not 100% sure what you're asking, but maybe `a = np.random.uniform(n,m, size=(10,10))` is what you are after?  See: [random.uniform](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.uniform.html) for more.

Comment: @Mark That's exactly what I needed to learn. I've never seen that before. Thank you!